# Acrobat X Pro Javascript How do I cause a radio button to causes a calculated field to add another calculation

Tags: javascript, radio-button, acrobat

I have several text fields formatted for numbers. Each text field is populated by a group of radio buttons resulting in a choice of numbers. A final text field is set up with a simple "value is the sum of" calculation of the other text fields in the Calculate window of the properties window.

The sum is a monthly billing number. I need to be able to also show it as an annual number, a simple x12 calculation. The trigger needs to be a pair of radio buttons with one for monthly and one for annual.

I am up against a wall. I tried to do this using two complete sets of buttons and fields, one for annual with the correct numbers and one for monthly. I used the show/hide feature to display only the chosen mode. The problem I encountered is that Field Calculation Order editor shows ALL pertinent fields on single slate instead of allowing me to create separate slates for the two options.

That results in one or the other calculations going wonky and returning some truly strange numbers.

This forced me to abandon the two sets of buttons and fields to combine them into one blob.

To make the world more complex I really need two versions of monthly and two versions of annual on the same page. We have Single rates and Family rates, and I would like to be able to hide one or the other based on a different pair of radio buttons.

What I need is a way to cause a numeric text field with a value derived from either a radio button or a calculation to be multiplied by 12 upon "demand" from a paired trigger. Radio buttons, check boxes or similar one click options.

The ideal outcome for me is to separate the Individual from the Family fields and set them up to hide/show with a pair of radio buttons. Then, whether it be finding a way to multiply the fields by 12, or by creating two more sets of buttons/fields to be hidden/shown, I want to switch between monthly and annual.

The big problem is that I don't know enough about JavaScript to know where to search for the answers.